# Personal VPN connects and works but Facebook and Youtube dose not open

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I configured a **personal VPN** in a **server** (Win 2012) and i can connect to it (with `L2TP` or `SSTP`) by a **client** (Win 8.1) and it has Internet.

................[image].............

---

**It works** and I can browse different sites (like this page) by it and now my internet `IP` is the `IP` of the server **but** i can't open **Facebook** and **Youtube** over the VPN connection **!!**

**The client** can't open these sites normally (even widthout VPN) *(because some internet censorship policies in the client region)*.

But **the server** is in a different region and if i try to open Facebook or Youtube by Remote Desktop in it, it open them without any problem.

I see someone write a similar question [here (in ShanghaiExpat site)](https://www.shanghaiexpat.com/forum/can-not-open-facebook-or-youtube-using-vpn-t133874.html).

**My tests (with No success)**:

- Configure `PPTP` VPN on the server and connect to it by client and test open youtube
- Configure `L2TP` VPN on the server and connect to it by client and test open youtube
- Configure `SSTP` VPN on the server and connect to it by client and test open youtube
- I tested **8.8.8.8 in DNS** part of Ethernet Interface.
- Test by **Firefox**
- Test by **Chrome**
- Browse by Chrome **incognito** windows
- Browser **Clear cache**
- **Restart Windows** of the client

**What do you think? and how i can solve this problem?**

---

**Update:**

I pinged **Google.com, Youtube.com, Facebook.com** while the VPN was connected in client and get **reply** for all of them:

[image]

But if i try to open it by Internet Browser Softwares it show me error:

**Firefox** (Error: `The connection has timed out`)

[image]

**Chrome** (Error: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`):

[image]

Comment: If you connect to the remote server using l2tp or sstp all traffic from client to the server will go through the vpn but if you connect to facebook or youtube, the traffic may go directly from your client to facebook (blocked) or youtube (blocked). You should make sure that 1) the l2tp or sttp routes ALL traffic to the remote server (use remote gateway) and 2) the remote server should be configured that it should route ALL traffic to the rest of the internet (windows conection sharing)

Comment: @anneb, i'm a beginner in networking so may you give me 2 atricle links about the 2 points that you mentioned in your comment (base Windows OS) please?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved the problem myself! The problem was about **DNS**.

I tried to **set DNS addresses manually** *in the settings of the **VPN connection*** and it works!

> VPN Connection settings » Networking Tab » TCP/IPv4 properties » DNS
>   addresses
>
> **4.2.2.4**
>
> **8.8.8.8**

If you have a same problem set the DNS addressed like mine:

[image]

Comment: This really worksssss!!! thank you very much!